# Disable only calendar modal of <input type = "date">

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to deactivate only the calendar modal that appears when clicking the calendar icon, in input of type date

`<input type="date">`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LdIz.png)

Comment: What about turning it into a `text` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the following styles:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
      display: none;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
  }
```

```css
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
      display: none;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
  }
```

```html
<input type="date">
```